# How do you force Flask to query database on each GET request?

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I have a very simple piece of code:

```
@app.route('/read')
def db_read():
    dbcursor.execute('SELECT * FROM books;')
    result = dbcursor.fetchall()
    return render_template('read.html', result=result)
```

When I start the server, everything works fine, however, if I make the changes to the database while the app is running, the changes are not reflected on /read page, the app has to be restarted to reflect them.
I expect the code to query database each time I refresh the page and the current behavior seems very counter-intuitive to me. Can someone please help?

Comment: You probably intialize `dbcursor` once when the app starts you have to initialize it every time inside the view code

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi sorry, doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: Then please post the code where you init the database and run the server so this way we can figure out where the problem is coming from

Comment: How did you initialize the cursor inside the view code following Amine's recommendation?

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi Here's the full version of the code: https://pastebin.com/LCNDe4BX

Comment: I've tried adding dbcursor = mydb.cursor() to the beginning of db_read function, but the result is still the same, sadly

Comment: Can show the code, how you have intialized the cursor?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD to true in your config? It should toggle ON when you run in debug mode but it seems like template reloading has always been a little buggy.

You should also be using the flask run --debug command as well. app.run has issues that the run command copes with.

Answer (score 0):

Your cursor is intialized withing the app instance hence queries executed are saved to the instance as read only, so changes reflected to the database are persistent within the instance.

There are several workarounds to overcome this isssue.

I would recommend you to create separate module for database instance and import where ever required.

**database.py**

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host=cfg['host'],
    user=cfg['user'],
    passwd=cfg['password'],
    database=cfg['database']
)

db = mydb.cursor()
```

**app.py**

```
from database import db

@app.route('/read') 
    def db_read():
        db.execute('SELECT * FROM books;')
         result = db.fetchall()
         return render_template('read.html', result=result)
```